# How to get typedef details using python and clang

Tags: python, c, clang, typedef

I am trying to get details from a C header. I am using python and clang to do it. To do that, I am using python and clang, but I am not managing to get the details.

I have checked the content of a `TYPEDEF_DECL` node but I don't see all the details.

For example, I am parsing the following line that can be found in `miniz.h`:

```
typedef mz_bool (*tdefl_put_buf_func_ptr)(const void *pBuf, int len, void *pUser);
```

I am managing to extract:

```
miniz.h    [   639/ 19] >TYPEDEF_DECL   : name=tdefl_put_buf_func_ptr
miniz.h    [   639/  9] >>TYPE_REF       : name=mz_bool
miniz.h    [   639/ 55] >>PARM_DECL      : name=pBuf
miniz.h    [   639/ 65] >>PARM_DECL      : name=len
miniz.h    [   639/ 76] >>PARM_DECL      : name=pUser
```

How can I get the `const void`, `int`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

The information is available within the `PARM_DECL` nodes. It is a bit hidden. It is in:

```
node.type.spelling
```